# Floor Function Proof by 2 Cases

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

I looked at a lot of questions and answers about this topic, and none seem to satisfy what I am looking for. Or it just was not obvious to me. Please help me understand.

In class, we partially proved that $\forall x\in R$ there exists a unique $n_0\in Z$ such that $n_0\le x< n_0+1$. We aim to show that $n_0$ is the floor function of $x$. I am having trouble finishing it, and understanding the intuition behind it. Here is how I understand the first part of the proof, and how I try to complete it:

**Proof:**

*First Case: $x>0$*

Let $A=\{n\in N;n>x\}\not=\emptyset$ (I assume we know this set exists because of the Archimedean Property which equivalently states that $\forall x>0\in R, \exists n\in N$ such that $n>x$. So the existence of such a "$n$" makes the set not empty)

This set is bounded below by $x$, so by the well-ordering principal of $N$, $min(N)$ exists. Let $m_0=min(A)$. So $m_0\in A$, so $m_0>x$, and $m_0-1\notin A$ as $m_0$ is the minimum of $A$. Since $\forall a\in A \implies a>x$ then $\forall a\notin A \implies a\le x$, so $m_0-1\le x$. Since $m_0-1$ is the biggest integer smaller or equal to  $x$, $m_0-1$ is the floor of $x$. Do I understand the first case correctly?

*Second Case: $x\le 0$*

This is my proof. I assume for the first case we had to juggle around to use the Archimedean Property because it does not directly imply the existence of an $n_0<x$. However for $x\le 0$, we have by the equivalent of the Archimedean Property that $\forall x<0\in R, \exists n\in Z$ such that a $n<x$. So I just take $n$ to be the $max(n\in Z; n\le x)$. Is this correct?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I replaced $N$ with $Z$ in case 2

Comment: Except for minor typos the essence is there. In the first case, you actually have $a \in A$ if and only if $a$ is an integer and $a > x$. Note is the other implication the one you are using, as $p$ implies $q$ is equivalent to $\neg q$ implies $\neg p$.

For the second case, what you are essentially using is that if $x < 0$ then the floor of x is minus the ceil of $-x$ (make a picture and this will be clear). Note that there are no natural numbers which are $\leq x$, and the max need not exist if the set is not bounded above. I suggest trying to define ceil for $x > 0$ first.

Comment: Alright, so can I prove the existence of the ceiling of $x$ by using the same set $A$ which would bound $x$ from above, and say that $min(n \in N;n\ge x)$ is the ceiling? Assuming I proved the ceiling exists, how do I show that the floor of $x<0$ is minus the celing $x>0$ @Lazward

Comment: Yes, that should work. See @Piquito 's answer for a hint on the equivalence. Note the ceil of x is the unique integer $n$ satisfying $n - 1 < x \leq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.-For $x\lt0$ you have $$n_0\le-(x)\lt n_0+1\iff -(n_0+1)\lt x\le -n_0$$

Comment: I worked out the following then: $\forall x\le 0 \in R, \exists n \in N$ such that $n>-x$ so $n+x>0$. Then we know that $\forall y>0 \in R$ there exists an $n_0$ such that $n_0 \le x < n_0+1$. Let $y=n+x$ which is positive, so $n_0 \le y < n_0+1$, so $-n_0 -1 < x \le n_0$. and so $-n_0-1$ is the floor, so the floor = minus celing?

Edit: Could you also help me understand why we dont have $n_0 \le x \le n_0+1$ instead of $n_0 \le x < n_0+1$

Comment: $n_0\le-(x)\iff x\le -n_0$

Comment: My question was silly I apologize, however, is my reasoning/proof correct?